# Shared Pointer based Object Pool Implementation with fixed object count

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing a object pool with shared_ptr to access with multiple thread.
Any suggestions to improve my implementation

```
template <typename T>
class Section : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Section<T>>
{
public:

template <typename... E>
Section(std::size_t size, E... args)
    : std::enable_shared_from_this<Section<T>>()
    , m_mem(size,T(args...))
{
    for(auto& itr: m_mem)
    {
        destroy(&itr);
        m_objs.push(&itr);
    }
}
virtual ~Section() = default;

void isEmpty() const
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
    return m_objs.empty();
}
template <typename... E>
std::shared_ptr<T> create(E... args)
{
    T* obj = getObject();       
    if(obj != nullptr)
    {
        new (obj) T(args...);
    }
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(obj,[this](T* ptr)->void
    {
        destroy(ptr);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        m_objs.push(ptr);
    });
}

private:
std::list<T> m_mem;
std::queue<T*> m_objs;
mutable std::mutex m_lock;


T* getObject()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
    if (!m_objs.empty())
    {
        T* obj = m_objs.front();
        m_objs.pop();
        return obj;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

void destroy(T* obj)
{
    obj->~T();
}       
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Small nitpicks

- The constructor and `create` could profit from perfect forwarding `args` (so references of all kinds can be used.

  ```
  template<typename... E>
  Section(size_t size, E&&... args) :
      std::enable_shared_from_this<Section<T>>(),
      m_mem(size, T(std::forward<E>(args)...))
      { /* ... */ }
  ```
- Do you have any specific reason to prefer `std::list<T>` over `std::vector<T>` for `m_mem`? `std::vector<T>` would use less memory (no pointers from each element to the next), and the memory used would be contiguous (so iterating over it is very likely faster due to cache effects).

## Correctness

Every `std::shared_ptr<T>` returned by `Section<T>::create()` might be dangling. This can happen if the `Section<T>` gets destroyed while there are still `std::shared_ptr<T>` pointing to contained objects.

**This is a result of the `std::shared_ptr<T>` not owning the pointer.**

If you can guarantee that there won't be any `std::shared_ptr<T>` pointing into the `Section<T>` when the `Section<T>` is destroyed, this problem easily disappears.

If this can't be guaranteed, there are two options:

1. Introducing your own smart pointer type that checks the `Section<T>` for validity every time it's dereferenced, as the standard smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`) are not designed for this task.
2. (Ab-)using the returned `std::shared_ptr<T>` to keep the section alive. This can be done in the lamda init capture of the custom deleter.

   ```
   return std::shared_ptr<T>(obj, [section = shared_from_this()](T *ptr) -> void
   {
       section->destroy(ptr);
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(section->m_lock);
       section->m_objs.push(ptr);
   });
   ```

   Note: This might keep the section alive far longer than intended! (Some might also say that this is an ugly hack...)